# setBackgroundResource on ImageView return null

Tags: java, android, listview, imageview, jquery-animate

I'm using ListFragment in my android project. I decided to make a listView, each listview item consist of music frequency imageView. I will try to animate the imageView of music frequency. Each listView has a button called play, once the play is clicked, the music frequency start to animate.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
         ViewGroup container,  Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmentmusiclist, container, false);
    lv = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.list);


    mp = new MediaPlayer();
    mp = null;

    Song s1 = new Song("Love Story",(float) 2.5, onMusicPlayListener);
    Song s2 = new Song("Sad Story",(float) 1.0, onMusicPlayListener);
    Song s3 = new Song("Breakup Story",(float) 3.5, onMusicPlayListener);

    songs = new ArrayList<Song>();
    songs.add(s1);
    songs.add(s2);
    songs.add(s3);

    adapter = new MusicListAdapter(getActivity(),songs);
    setListAdapter(adapter);


    return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
}

OnClickListener onMusicPlayListener = new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
  final int position = getListView().getPositionForView((LinearLayout)v.getParent());
  animMusicFreq = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.music_anim);
  animMusicFreq.setBackgroundResource(R.anim.anim_music);
  animMusicFreq.post(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        AnimationDrawable frameAnimation =
            (AnimationDrawable) animMusicFreq.getBackground();
                    frameAnimation.start();
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are inflating your view inside `onCreateView`, but you don't pass it to the system. Instead you tell it to inflate its own (you return `super`). It doesn't make any sense.

You should return your `v` view like so:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container,  Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmentmusiclist, container, false);
    // ...
    return v;
}
```